# Built in fragment crashes on emulator

Tags: android

I'm a beginner in Android programming. I'm trying to work with the built-in fragment in the android studio.I just tried editing the .xml in the main content part and tried to run the program but it crashes in the emulator.

```
<LinearLayout
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    app:layout_behavior="@string/appbar_scrolling_view_behavior"
    tools:context="com.example.danger.fragmentss.MainActivity"
    tools:showIn="@layout/activity_main"
    android:weightSum="1">

  <fragment
      android:layout_width="wrap_content"
      android:layout_height="match_parent"
      android:id="@+id/f1"
      android:layout_weight="3.14"
      android:name="com.example.danger.fragmentss.BlankFragment"></fragment>
    <fragment
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:name="com.example.danger.fragmentss.BlankFragment2"
        android:id="@+id/f2"></fragment>

    </LinearLayout>
```

Only this I did and its crashing

Comment: give orientation to your linearLayout like `orientation = vertical`

Comment: put your `Logcat` code